# Enable/Disable APEX dynamic action

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a form which has 4 items:

1. A yes or no fill in
2. 2 items if yes
3. 1 item if no

I would like to create a dynamic action that would disable the field(s) that I do not need, enable the one(s) that I do need, and set the focus to the (first) enabled item. 
*Additionally*, it should be able to switch back and forth without a page refresh.

I tried making a couple of dynamic actions, but I noticed that it would only change once. For example, if I were to enter 'yes' into the first field, it would enable and disable the appropriate fields, but when I would switch the first field to 'no', nothing would changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to fill in the Condition field (in the When sction) on the dynamic action and then include a True Action and a False Action.

For example:

```
Condition equal to 'Yes'
True Actions:  Display 2 items
               Hide 1 item
False Actions:  Hide 2 items
                Display 1 item
```

If this doesn't resolve your issue, you should try listing the values you have used for all the fields on your dynamic actions.  Without seeing the values, it is difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: This helps the first part of my question. The difficulty that I'm having is that if I were to change the fill-in, the fields that I want disabled will not be enabled and the reverse as well because they were previously disabled/enabled by the first fill-in.